# Dangers with unscoped multiline MACROS

Tags: c++, multiline, visual-studio-macros

Is there a way to protect this MACRO from unscoped if/for statements?

```
#define FOO(X, Y, ...) X->bar(_##Y->thatVar, __VA_ARGS__);\
post_op(X, Y)
```

The order of bar and post_op is important and the result of post_op is ignorable to the application

i.e.

```
if(true)
    auto z = FOO(a,b);
else //compile error
    abort();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-macros

Comment: Full protection can be achieved by not using macros.

Comment: @StoryTeller it cannot be used for MACROs with return value

Comment: A macro spanning multiple statements cannot have a "return value". You really ought to come into better grasp with how macros behave. They are token replacement, no more.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I over-simplified my application. Question has been edited.

Comment: @StoryTeller I see no real difference from token perspective; between multi-line macros and macros with return value

Comment: Multiple statements, not multiple lines, was my exact phrasing for a reason. Lines are immaterial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a lambda to reaggregate your statements back into an expression. Use it wherever an expression may appear, to your heart's content. Even in an expression statement inside an `if` with no braces.

```
#define FOO(X, Y, ...) [&] { \ 
  auto ret = X->bar(_##Y->thatVar, __VA_ARGS__);\
  post_op(X, Y); \
  return ret; }()
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanx a million!